Apollo Server nested resolvers and Typescript object incompatibility
I have the following GraphQL schema
type Item {
  name: String!
  color: String!
  price: Float!
}

type Query {
  items: [Item]
}

The schema is then ingested by https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator and the generated types are included at the bottom.
And in apollo, the following resolver object is defined:
{
  Item: {
    price: () => 1.0,
  },
  Query: {
    items: () => [
      { name: 'item1', color: 'red' },
      { name: 'item2', color: 'blue' },
    ],
  },
}

This works fine with a query like this:
query {
  items {
    name
    color
    price
  }
}

However, with this setup, Typescript complains that the items resolver is returning an incompatible type missing the price property. This is because the generated type makes price non-nullable and Typescript is not aware that price will be resolved later into a non-null float value.
The exact error is:
Type '() => { name: string; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>[]>, {}, ApolloContext, {}> | undefined'.
  Type '() => { name: string; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResolverFn<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>[]>, {}, ApolloContext, {}>'.
    Type '{ name: string; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>[]> | Promise<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>[]>>'.
      Type '{ name: string; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>[]'.
        Type '{ name: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ResolverTypeWrapper<Item>'.
          Property 'price' is missing in type '{ name: string; color: string; }' but required in type 'Item'. (tsserver 2322)

Am I missing anything in terms of defining these types in Apollo with respect to Typescript? How should this be resolved?
I understand that one way to solve this would be to mark price as nullable by removing the ! from the schema definition, but that seems like a hack and only applicable in this minimal example. In real world usage, you could have any number of non-nullable fields that make sense to be resolved later because they asynchronous or simply expensive. So the correct schema should be defining non-null fields.
Generated types based on the schema above:
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type InputMaybe<T> = Maybe<T>;
export type Exact<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
export type MakeOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]?: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
export type MakeMaybe<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };
export type MakeEmpty<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }, K extends keyof T> = { [_ in K]?: never };
export type Incremental<T> = T | { [P in keyof T]?: P extends ' $fragmentName' | '__typename' ? T[P] : never };
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: { input: string; output: string; }
  String: { input: string; output: string; }
  Boolean: { input: boolean; output: boolean; }
  Int: { input: number; output: number; }
  Float: { input: number; output: number; }
};

export type Item = {
  __typename?: 'Item';
  name: Scalars['String']['output'];
  color: Scalars['String']['output'];
  price: Scalars['Float']['output'];
};

export type Query = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  items?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Item>>>;
};


How exactly did you generate the TypeScript types (from your schema I presume) and how did you apply them to that code? You'll need to show us a [mcve] of the full TypeScript code throwing this error, or we can't help you.

"items: [Item]" means an array of one "items: Item[]" is an array of many items. there maybe some other issues in there I didn't spot yet, but immediately I can see the type their is expecting an array with one Item only. It may not completely be the cause noting  Promise<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper[]>> should actually be  Promise<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<Item[]>>> . Last suggestion si to ensure the caller is using the right type from the right dependency. Item is generic you could easily be importing the wrong type or have defined something inline by accident

@Bergi, I edited the post and added a little bit more details. And you are right, I should have tried to make a fully reproduced example in code sandbox. In the process of trying so, I actually discovered the root cause here. I will post my findings below. Thanks for the help!

I've found the root cause. It's an incomplete type generated for the resolvers by typescript-resolvers plugin. In short, it is not fully taking into account all "resolvable" fields because the outputs from resolvers are directly taken from the type definitions in GraphQL schema, but that's an incomplete picture.
More discussions can be found here and here
